# DataGrid in an UpdatePanel doing full Refresh when clicking on column headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a DataGrid on an asp.net webforms page in an unconditional `UpdatePanel`: `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upData" runat="server">` .

DataBinding occurs inside `protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)` , as I process any user events before performing the binding.  Clicking on the headers works properly (i.e., triggers a sort), but causes a full page refresh rather than refreshing just the `UpdatePanel`.

I did find a way to fix this, but it's pretty horrifying (`dgGrid` being the `DataGrid`):

```
foreach (Control c in dgGrid.Controls[0].Controls[1].Controls)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(c.Controls[0]);
}
```

Can anyone suggest a cleaner way to fix this?

Comment: I think paging,sorting, etc with gv inside UP should work without any issues. Check an example here: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/indepth_the_updatepanel_aspnet.html So wondering if there is something else causing that.

Comment: @gbs: Well, the `LinkButton`s that are next to the `GridView` for paging *do* work without this issue.

Comment: But as you see in the link's demo even Sort Link in header is working fine inside UP. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @gbs: Well, the link performs the databinding using an SqlDataSource.  I perform it during the codebehind.  I think that's where our strategies differ.

Comment: Ahhh...finally I am out of clue ;)

Comment: Here is a really very basic sample I tried to see if I can replicate: http://pastebin.com/XeJcm82k but wasn't able to reproduce. See if that does some good.

Answer (score 0):

add the following as a trigger to your UpdatePanel

```
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dgGrid" />
            </Triggers>
```